# Uncaught ReferenceError: myfunction is not defined at HTMLDivElement.onclick - Slider Revolution

Tags: javascript, wordpress, onclick

I need some help with a little code that I've made for vimeo embed videos customization with two "buttons" that play/pause and mute/unmute the media. I have some HTML and Javascript:

```
<div>
  <video id="video1" width="1920"  autoplay playsinline>
    <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/298001970.hd.mp4?s=0d1ad3aae3905d0801db4f4d0dc4a843a666a3f8&profile_id=175" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

  <div id="playbutton1" class="VideoPlayer__PlayButton" onclick="playPause(); changetext();">PAUSE</div> 

  <div class="mutebutton">
  <div  class="VideoPlayer__MuteButton" onclick="muteunmute()">MUTE</div> </div> 
 </div> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1"); 
var textbutton = document.getElementById("playbutton1"); 

function playPause() { 
  if (myVideo.paused) 
    myVideo.play(); 
  else 
    myVideo.pause();
} 

function muteunmute(){
    if (myVideo.muted === false) {    
       myVideo.muted = true;
}

    else {
        myVideo.muted = false;
    }
}

function changetext() {
    if (textbutton.innerHTML === "PAUSE")
    {
    textbutton.innerHTML = "PLAY";
  } else {
    textbutton.innerHTML = "PAUSE";
  }
}
</script>
```

Now, in a blank page it works but I need to put it inside a Slider Revolution (I've used a text layer) on Wordpress. When I do it the console gives me this error every time I click on one of the two button: "**Uncaught ReferenceError: myfunction is not defined     at HTMLDivElement.onclick**"

Thanks a lot!